# looking for a distributed key value database for persistence

Tags: database, persistence, key-value-store

I'm looking for an efficient key-value distributed persistent database.

- I've look into Redis, but it only support hashes with up to $2^{32}$ keys, which is not enough for my application
- I've look into Memcached, but it is not designed for long-term persistence, it is designed for keys-value pairs to expire after a while
- I've look into BerkeleyDB, but does not support a client-server paradigm, it is basically a in-app storage engine
- I've look into HyperTable, but is not really row-oriented, you cannot edit existing rows unless you want to hack the timestamps, and after a key + timestamp is deleted, it cannot be reinserted. Also, the only supported value type are strings, if you want to store floats or complex objects you need to serialize into a string and then deserialize
- I've look into MongoDB, which is very flexible, but it has suffered from very important performance and scalability issues that haven't been addressed in the last two years. They are summarized in this [blog post](http://blog.engineering.kiip.me/post/20988881092/a-year-with-mongodb).

I'm going to look next into Cassandra and Riak, and as you see i'm quickly running out of real options

What other databases are there that can fit the description i've outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CouchDB. http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/why.html

It is a non-relational database, open-source, distributed (incremental, bidirectional replication), schema-free. Data is stored in documents formatted as JSON. It has robust persistence and is a distributed key value database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/fastdht

It is a high performance distributed hash table based on Berkeley DB.